# Sending an e-mail in asp.net using vb

Tags: asp.net, email

error  :The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at

I tried all things that i can do for this error ,but unable to solve this. Please help!!
My .net code for sending e-mail is as follows:

```
  Try
        Dim oMsg As MailMessage = New MailMessage()
        Dim sendr, receivr As MailAddress
        sendr = New MailAddress("username@gmail.com")
        receivr = New MailAddress(TextBox4.Text)
        oMsg.From = sendr
        oMsg.To.Add(receivr)
        oMsg.Subject = "Asp.net testing"
        oMsg.IsBodyHtml = True
        oMsg.Body = "Hi everyOne"
        'oMsg.BodyFormat = MailFormat.Html
        'oMsg.Body = "<HTML><BODY><B>Dear " & TextBoxName.Text & "</B></br></br>Congratulations! You have been successfully registered.</br></br>"
        'oMsg.Body = oMsg.Body & "Your Username is: " & TextBox1.Text & "</br>Your Password is: " & TextBox2.Text & " </br>Regards,</br>team SMVDU.</BODY></HTML>"

        Dim client As SmtpClient = New SmtpClient()
        Dim cred As System.Net.NetworkCredential = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("username@gmail.com", "*******", "smtp.gmail.com")
        client.Credentials = cred
        client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"
        client.Port = 587
        client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network
        client.EnableSsl = True
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = False
        client.Send(oMsg)
        Response.Write("<script>alert('E-mail sent')</script>")
    Catch ex As Exception
        Response.Write("" & ex.Message)
    End Try
```

I am using windows 7 home basic. And all things that can be given is correct i.e email, password from my side.

Comment: I don't know if you need to specify the domain for the credentials. Have you tried without it? `New System.Net.NetworkCredential("username@gmail.com", "*******")`

Comment: I think you need an admin to set up your mail relay so you can send mail. It may not be set up to allow your web server to relay. (used to happen to me all the time)

Comment: Try using port 465 for the SMTP SSL port. `client.Port = 465`

Comment: first remove the domain for the credentials as michael said, next remove the DeliveryMethod and UseDefaultCredentials lines then make sure that you've inserted a valid email and password in credentials and it should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot u all.It worked @jack Kokah .It would be more helpful for me ,if you can give some detail explanation for that, as i am novice in this field.